# SHA1 key certification for release mode in android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-authentication

I'm using SHA1 debugging key in firebase for debugging my application, but I want to release my app in the play store where I'm providing Google authentication in my application.

What can I do for release mode where do I get SHA1 release mode certificate and what can I do with that?

Is it necessary to download the json file again?  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this [enter link description here](http://fabcoding.com/how-to-obtain-sha1-keys-for-debug-and-release-android-studio-mac/)

Basiclly what he did, and for me works fine, is one you upload the app to google play:

1. Go to Release Management
2. Select App Signing
3. Use the SHA1 that you see there in FireBase